# Zope and buildout: Python modules

Tags: python, zope, buildout

I set up a Zope installation using buildout. For one of my Zope-products I need some additional python-modules, so I figured it would be smart not to install them system-wide but in the buildout.

I need beautifulsoup4, so I that's what I tried:

```
[buildout]
parts = ...
        beautifulsoup4

[beautifulsoup4]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg

[zopepy]
...
eggs = ...
       beautifulsoup4
```

When I run a buildout, I get the message that beautifulsoup4 was installed. A peek into the zopepy shows me

```
sys.path[0:0] = [
    ...
    '/opt/Zope2-2.13.21/eggs/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py2.7.egg',
    ...
```

But when I start my Zope instance, I get: *ImportError: No module named bs4*

What's the correct way to install additional Python products in a Zope buildout?

Answer (score 2):

A few necessary corrections:

(1) You do not need to care about the zopepy part, that is just a part for an interpreter script, not for the instance itself.  If you care about sys.path in both the bin/instance and bin/zopepy script (you should), make sure that you have this in [buildout] eggs= and just make sure eggs = option in instance includes ${buildout:eggs}

(2) What matters is that your [instance] part has your beautifulsoup4 egg added to its eggs option.

(3) To accomplish the above, you do not need a [beautifulsoup4] part, that is unnecessary.

(4) You really should pin a version for your distribution.

Should look like this:

```
[buildout]
eggs =
    beautifulsoup4
versions = versions

[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
...
eggs = 
    ${buildout:eggs}

[zopepy]
...
eggs = ${instance:eggs}

[versions]
beautifulsoup4 = 4.3.2
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I want. I don't want to build an instance this way, I'd just like to have a working Zope installation and to create instances using mkzopeinstance (by the way I'm not using Plone). So the instance-section is probably not the way to go for me, or is it?

Comment: @Rastaf: then why are you using buildout? That is what I use buildout for, to have *it* handle creating an instance.

Comment: @Martijn: I want to be able to manage different Zope versions (i.e. 2.13.19 and 2.13.21) on a server. You pointed me to buildout, so I went for it :)
I assumed that I could install a Zope version and all the Python modules I needed in conjunction with this version, then build as many instances from it as I liked. In fact, the first part of it is working only it seems that I can't use the additional Python modules in an old-style product. As I'm new to buildout I assumed I just did not set it up correctly.

Comment: I guess old-style products in an instance use the standard Python interpreter and not the one "created" from buildout (zopepy). So I have to update the sys.path in the __init__.py of my product.

Comment: That is an incorrect guess. I also pointed you to `virtualenv`, by the way. Use that for command-line tools.

Comment: You are right (as always). Virtualenv works like a charm for me and took me just a few minutes to set up. Thanks again.